# Redis - hmset() in hash - efficiency

Tags: hash, redis

Let us say there is a Redis hash that has 10 key - vals. I read them all into a perl hash ( or any language map/hash/dict ) and need to update 3 of the values. Now I changed the 3 values in the hash, and need to write it back to redis. among (A) & (B) which one will be faster?

(A) `$redis_handle->hmset($redis_hash_name,\%perl_hash);`

or

(B)  `while ( ($k,$val) = each %three_changed_items_in_perl_hash ) {
           $redis_handle->hset($redis_hash_name,$k,$val);
        }`

What I am trying to contemplate is :
(A) is one communication to redis with 10 elements. But redis needs to update only 3 of them. Does redis waste time even if values is not changed?
(B) is three communicaitons to redis with 1 element.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest would be to send a single `HMSET` that only has the updated fields and their respective values. Redis will only update these fields and will not do anything with the ones that aren't explicitly mentioned.

```
(C) $redis_handle->hmset($redis_hash_name,\%three_changed_items_in_perl_hash);
```

Comment: +1 . But more of my doubt is "Will redis ignore those unchanged values in hash?" . Otherwise, I need to loop through and note down the changed ones in perl when doing (C).

Comment: it will not ignore them so they'll be updated to the same value they were which is wasteful in terms of network and CPU - just prepare a hash that consists only of the changes and send that.